# Adding data to JSON file

Tags: python, json, raspberry-pi

I am working with a RaspberryPi using python. I want to send the data from the temp sensor to a JSON file. However, I am not sure how to do this. I would really appreciate some guidance on this matter. Thank you!

Here is my code:

```
import grovepi
import math
from time import sleep
from grove_rgb_lcd import *

sensor = 4

blue = 0
white = 1

setRGB(0,255,0)

while True:
    try:
        [temp,humidity] = grovepi.dht(sensor,blue)
        if math.isnan(temp) == False and math.isnan(humidity) == False:
            print("temp = %.02f C humidity =%.02f%%"%(temp, humidity))
        
        t = str(temp)
        h = str(humidity)
        
        setText("Temp:" + t + "C\n" + "Humidity :" + h + "%")
            
    except (IOError, TypeError) as e:
        print(str(e))
        setText("")
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print(str(e))
        setText("")
        break
    
    sleep(0.05)
```

Comment: I don't think you want to send data to a JSON file. I assume that rather you want to send data via JSON? You can construct a JSON in python by first populating a dictionary and then using the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

Comment: put the data in a dictionary and `json.dump()` it https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [json module](https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-xml-json/#:%7E:text=The%20JSON%20module%20is%20mainly,be%20written%20into%20a%20file.&text=While%20the%20JSON%20module%20will,write%20directly%20from%20JSON%20files.) for this, I have listed to functions below that show reading and writing to JSON files:

```py
import json

def read_json(file_path:str) -> dict:
    """Takes in a json file path and returns it's contents"""
    with open(file_path, "r") as json_file:
        content = json.load(json_file)
    return content

def store_json(data:dict, file_path:str):
    """Takes in a python dict and stores it as a .json file"""
    with open(file_path, "w") as json_file:
        json.dump(data, json_file)
```

Make sure you pass a dict to `store_json()`, or it will error out.

In your case I think you want:

```py
data = {}
data["temp"] = t
data["humidity"] = h

store_json(data, "path/to/file.json")
```

Comment: Thank you! Additional Question: 
I am reading the output on a .txt file. However, my temperature and humidity data are being displayed as "nan". Why is this happening?

Comment: @ZaneBrown there could be a number of things causing this. Nan means Not a Number. Your sensor could be sensing wrong, or the data is getting garbled somewhere. Try printing out the values of both right after they're read in.